# Вывод кода в value

Tags: javascript

Мне нужно вывести большие коды (примеры) с помощью **value:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Vmy(obj){
if (obj.elements[0][1].selected)
obj.res.value="border-radius: 35px;";
if (obj.elements[0][2].selected)
obj.res.value="ещё какой-нибудь код";
if (obj.elements[0][3].selected)
obj.res.value="и ещё какой-нибудь код";
}
</script>
```

Этот код работает. А вот если в `obj.res.value=` поместить более сложный код, то js перестаёт работать.
*Может быть, брать значения value из txt?*

Не знаю. Я только осваиваю JS. Спасибо за понимание и помощь!

Comment: Хотелось бы увидеть **более сложный код**, или ждите следующего экстрасенса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Экранируйте **`"`**.

Вот так, например:

```
obj.res.value = "
  <div class=\"item-some\"></div>
  <div class=\"item-some\"></div>
";
```

Если конечно код очень большой, то да - его лучше грузить из файла.